# Assigning values from a cell to another

Tags: c#

```
int rowsCount = 0;
//This checks to see that both textbox for items and subitems do not gain focus at the same time
if (textBoxSubItems.Text != string.Empty)
    txtItems.Enabled = false;
else 
    txtItems.Enabled = true;
if (comboBoxItems.SelectedItem != null)
{

    int idx = dataGridViewTimesheet.Rows.Add();
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewTimesheet.Rows[idx];
    row.Cells["items"].Value = comboBoxItems.SelectedItem.ToString() + "-" + textBoxSubItems.Text;
    row.Cells["fromTime"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    row.Cells["toTime"].Value = null;
    row.Cells["duration"].Value = null;
    row.Cells["subTotal"].Value = null;
    // row.Cells["comments"].Value = "1";
}
else 
    MessageBox.Show("Please select an item");

string strGetColumnValue;
if (dataGridViewTimesheet.Rows.Count != 0)
    rowsCount = dataGridViewTimesheet.Rows.Count;
else
    MessageBox.Show("No row in the datagridview");
while (dataGridViewTimesheet.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        if (dataGridViewTimesheet.CurrentRow != null)
            for (int counter = 0; counter < dataGridViewTimesheet.Columns.Count; counter++)
            {
                if (dataGridViewTimesheet.Columns[counter].Index == 3)
                {
                    strGetColumnValue = dataGridViewTimesheet.Rows[rowsCount].Cells[counter].Value.ToString();
                    dataGridViewTimesheet.Rows[rowsCount - 1].Cells[3].Value = strGetColumnValue;
                }
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Please i have 6 columns in a datagridview, the rows are added dynamically. What i want is when rows are more than one in the datagridview it should assign the value of the second column on the current(the last row created) row to the third column of the previous row. How do I achieve this.

Comment: What is the purpose of moving all the values down? This is not common and may be a result of incorrect logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this kind of thing

```
  int count =1;
  foreach (DataGridRow row in dataGridViewTimesheet.Rows)
  { 
     if (count % 2 == 0)
     {
       string secondColumn = dataGridViewTimesheet.Rows[count -1].Cells[1].ToString();
       dataGridViewTimesheet.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value = secondColumn;
     }
    count++;
  }
```